# ¿Cómo encuentro la ruta del archivo usando php?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Tengo este árbol de carpetas de un proyecto, estoy usando Ubuntu y PHP

```
jp@JP:/opt/lampp/htdocs/curso$ tree
.
├── clases
│   ├── Conexion.php
│   └── Estudiante.php
├── css
├── imagenes
├── index.php
├── js
└── modulos
    ├── Controlador.php
    └── Enrutador.php

5 directories, 5 files
```

Y tengo este error:

> Warning: include_once(../clases/Estudiante.php): failed to open stream: No existe el archivo o el directorio in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso/modulos/Controlador.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../clases/Estudiante.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso/modulos/Controlador.php on line 2

El código del archivo es este:

```
<?php 
    include_once('../clases/Estudiante.php');
    class controladorEstudiantes{

        //atributos
        private $estudiante; 


        //metodos
        public function __construct(){
            $this->estudiante = new Estudiante();
        }
        public function index()
        {
            $resultado = $this->estudiante->listar();
            return $resultado;
        }
        public function crear($cedula, $nombre, $apellido, $telefono, $edad, $nota1, $nota2, $nota3){

            $promedio = ($nota1 + $nota2 + $nota3) / 3;
            $this->estudiante->set("cedula", $cedula);
            $this->estudiante->set("nombre", $nombre);
            $this->estudiante->set("apellido", $apellido);
            $this->estudiante->set("telefono", $telefono);
            $this->estudiante->set("edad", $edad);
            $this->estudiante->set("promedio", $promedio);

            $resultado = $this->estudiante->crear();
            return $resultado;

        }
        public function eliminar($id){
            $this->estudiante->set("id", $id);
            $this->estudiante->eliminar();
        }
        public function ver($id){
            $this->estudiante->set("id", $id);
            $this->estudiante->ver();
        }
        public function editar($id){
            $this->estudiante->set("id", $id);
            $this->estudiante->ver();
            $this->estudiante->editar();

        }

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: ¿En qué directorio está el código que acabas de compartir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta así amigo a ver.

```
include_once('clases/Estudiante.php');
```

Comment: Podrias ayudarme tengo otro error

Comment: @JoséPabloSantizo claro jajaja dale cuenta que es el error

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta solucione el problema, no ayuda a futuros visitantes, pues falta contexto para entender porque funciona.

Comment: @JaimeMateus https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99933/c%C3%B3mo-soluciono-el-problema-del-enrutador-en-php

Comment: @JaimeMateus como te indican otros comentarios, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para solucionar el problema, sería ideal que añadieses una descripción del por qué o cómo funciona para que también sea de ayuda a otros usuarios que puedan encontrarse con el mismo problema. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] en el centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Doy por hecho que estas en jndex.php, si es asi no te salgas del directorio, o sea ../ te estas saliendo al directorio padre usa include('./clases/estudiantes.php') y si es al mismo nivel solo pon el nombre del script tambien puedes usar la constante dir include(**DIR**.'/clase/Estudiantes.php') esto eses desde index, si es desde modulo usa los dos puntos ../clases