# Undefined index en GET

Tags: php

Árbol de carpetas:

```
jp@JP:/opt/lampp/htdocs/curso$ tree
.
├── clases
│   ├── Conexion.php
│   └── Estudiante.php
├── css
├── imagenes
├── index.php
├── js
└── modulos
    ├── Controlador.php
    └── Enrutador.php

5 directories, 5 files
```

Archivo `index.php`:

```
<?php 
    include_once('modulos/Enrutador.php');
    include_once('modulos/Controlador.php');

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>POO en PHP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Bienvenidos todos los estudiantes
        </h1>

        <section>
            <?php 
                $enrutador = new Enrutador();
                $enrutador->cargarVista($_GET['cargar']);
             ?>
        </section>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Archivo `Enrutador.php`:

```
<?php 
    class Enrutador{

        public function cargarVista($vista){

            switch ($vista): 

                case "crear":
                    include_once('vistas/' . $vista . '.php');
                    break;

                default:
                    include_once('vistas/error.php');



            endswitch;

        }
    }
 ?>
```

Errores cuando lo ejecuto:

> Bienvenidos todos los estudiantes
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cargar in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso/index.php on line 21
>
> Warning: include_once(vistas/error.php): failed to open stream: No existe el archivo o el directorio in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso/modulos/Enrutador.php on line 13
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'vistas/error.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso/modulos/Enrutador.php on line 13

Comment: Estás llamando a un archivo de la carpeta vistas, pero dicha carpeta no existe en la estructura que muestras. ¿?

Comment: Esto: Notice: Undefined index: cargar in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso/index.php on line 21

Comment: @JoséPabloSantizo No tienes la carpeta vistas en tu estructura.

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta para agregar como solucionar la otra parte del error.

Answer (score 1):

El primer error o "Notice" es porque probablemente no estás pasando ningún valor en la URL para el índice cargar, para evitar que aparezca dicho error, puedes hacer una comprobación como esta:

```
$enrutador->cargarVista(isset($_GET['cargar']) ? $_GET['cargar'] : '');
```

---

El segundo error es bastante explícito y se evidencia fácilmente en la estructura de carpetas y archivos que muestras:

> No existe el archivo `vistas/error.php`, de hecho ni siquiera existe la carpeta `vistas`.